# How to make a cycles light emisson object invisible to the camera?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera, light

In my scene it is required to position **the lights close to the main object** like this:

[image]

How I can make the **light source invisible to the camera**?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can **turn off** *Ray Visibility* of the 'emission object'. In **Blender 3.0+** go to *Object Properties > Visibility*, open up the *Ray Visibility* panel and disable the *Camera* property:

[image]

---

As of **Blender 2.8x**, *Ray Visibility* panel is now part of the new *Visibility Panel*:

[image]

---

As of **Blender 2.76** the *Ray Visibility* panel was renamed to *Cycles Settings*:

[image]

---

**Blender 2.7x**

[image]

---

You can also run the following script to *toggle* the *Camera Ray Visibility* for *all selected objects*:

**Blender 3.1+**

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:

    # toggle mesh lights
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        for slot in obj.material_slots:
            if slot.material:
                for node in slot.material.node_tree.nodes:
                    if node.type == "EMISSION":
                        obj.visible_camera = not obj.visible_camera

    # toggle light types
    if obj.type == 'LIGHT':
        obj.visible_camera = not obj.visible_camera
```

**Blender 2.8+**

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:

    # toggle mesh lights
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        for slot in obj.material_slots:
            if slot.material:
                for node in slot.material.node_tree.nodes:
                    if node.type == "EMISSION":
                        obj.cycles_visibility.camera = not obj.cycles_visibility.camera

    # toggle light types
    if obj.type == 'LIGHT':
        obj.cycles_visibility.camera = not obj.cycles_visibility.camera
```

Comment: Both of the answers produce the same result, but just to add that in the node setup you have much more control over things.

Comment: @Vladimir Note that disabling visibility in the object settings is slightly more efficient performance wise than a node setup.

Comment: @gandalf3 I didn't know that. But, maybe the node setup can be more useful if the performance is here there the same. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Does not work correctly, it still appears in the bake

Comment: Can I also exclude it from compositing layers like depth or normals?

Answer (score 22):

You can set up a **custom emission material** by adding another [Transparent BSDF](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/transparent.html) and determine the (camera) visibility of each shader at render time by using the *Is Camera Ray* output of the [Light Path](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/light_path.html) node that serves as the *Factor* for the [Mix Shader](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/mix.html) node:

[image]

**Note:** [@gandalf3 mentioned](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17910/how-to-make-a-cycles-light-emisson-object-invisible-to-the-camera#comment25276_17918) that disabling the *Ray Visibility* is slightly more efficient performance-wise than this node setup.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Well, in Blender 2.79 just turning the camera ray off did not work as I expected. So I did a new trick. It Works fine for me.

Comment: Answers should be more in depth than a simple screenshot. What did you do differently? Why was the accepted answer insufficient? FWIW, the accepted answer still works fine in 2.79, something else must be different in your scene. Is your light behind glass, for example? That would cause rays hitting it to be transmissions rays rather than camera rays.