# How to make emisive materials produce more light without changing how it looks

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, lighting

[image] So, i need some help. As you can see in the image, there is a *fireball* with smoke. problem is, the smoke is barely visible but i need it to be visible in the final render. how can i do that by changing how bright the fire is, without the fire seeming brighter?

Comment: I don't know whether this approach works for your material, but maybe a Light Path node like in [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/17913/34236) will work. Instead of a transparent shader you would have to use a duplicate of the original shader with different emission strength.

Comment: i'll try that and see how it works out.

Comment: Or just use a lamp? not sure if it would work for you