# Lamps still showing on render

Tags: rendering, lighting, visibility

I have a problem with the lamps in my animation. I have used multiple sun lamps to animate welding so these lamps are switched on and off at the right frame throughout the animation. However, after the welding is complete and the lamps are turned off, there still seems to be the lamps showing when everything else fades out of visibility. The background is completely black at the end, so these lamps really stand out. It seems they are not emitting any light either. Just the pixels are there.Also, there is a big reflection of the floor surface of another spotlight.

Is there a way to have the actual light source emit light but not be reflected on selected surfaces so i dont see a big dumb white circle (the lamp) on the highly reflective floor?

And also, can anyone help with the lamps that are still showing when they are turned off? I have un-ticked "camera" in the ray visibility cycle settings for each lamp as well as restricted the rendering for each.

Many thanks in advance for anyones help. Greatly appreciated.

please click the 2 to see rendered image. Sorry i'm new to this.

Alex[image: These lights shouldnt exist![![Position of lamps match with render]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FdaE.png)

Comment: Could you describe by which way you turn them off? Also what is your world settings?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17910/how-to-make-a-cycles-light-emisson-object-invisible-to-the-camera

Comment: Hi Lemon,
I turn off the lights by restricting the render at the selected keyframes. So i basically click the restrict render camera icon in the bodies list (top right corner) at a frame and set a key frame then at the end of the animation i set another restrict render keyframe so it clearly shows on the dope sheet that it stays off. Funny thing is, this works throughout the series of lights in the animation. Just little pixels show at the end when everything is completely dark.
World settings are as default, just background colour changed to black.