# Prevent the light source from appearing in the reflection

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, lighting

I have a glossy, metallic ball, rendered below. My problem is that you can clearly see the two lights used in the render. This lighting looks O.K. in the example, but what would I do if I wanted to remove the lighting from the reflection?

Note that I do still want the reflection, I just don't want the huge white spots. I also don't really want the brightness or position of the light to be noticeably changed.

Bonus question: Would there perhaps be a way to just soften the lighting rather than completely removing the white patches? Is there perhaps a way to make the white spots slightly darker without affecting the brightness of the light, or maybe a way to just smoothen out the white patches, so it is more of a gradient?

[image: Notice the two big white patches, caused by the reflection of the light? I wanna get rid of that.]

Comment: see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17910/how-to-make-a-cycles-light-emisson-object-invisible-to-the-camera

Comment: I don't believe that this is what I am looking for. It seems that in this article,   it simply makes it so that the object is unaffected by the light, making the object black. I would like to keep the shading but just remove (or at least make less obvious) the large white spots.

Comment: I don't think what you are asking makes any sense. The two white dots spots *are* the reflection. The light hitting the ball is the only reason you can see it. You could make your lights invisible to the surface, but then were would be nothing to display.

Comment: A glossy object will reflect things around it.  You have a black environment (nothing to be reflect on your object but the light sources), if you make it so the object will not reflect the light sources...   What do you expect to see? You will have a black screen.

Comment: Please read this related post: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black/50576#50576

Answer (score 4):

In cycles, go to your material that emits light. Your setup should look like this:[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Blender Internal, and all you wish to do is remove reflected points of light, simply go to each light source's properties and switch off (untick) "Specular".

[image] [image]

In the 2nd image the left lamp's 'Specular'  has been unticked, which takes off the point of light reflection but leaves it's lighting effect intact.

As pointed out in the comments above, removing both would also remove the ball's shiny surface effect!  One point at least should remain

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but I'll just find some way around my problem. Probably should have also clarified that I'm using cycles.