# How to hide light object in a mirror?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

The lights themselves are not visible, but they are visible in reflective materials such as mirrors.
how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Does this help ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77987/prevent-the-light-source-from-appearing-in-the-reflection

Comment: you can disable the Glossy option in the Properties panel > Object > Visibility > Ray Visibility

Comment: thank you ,it's very helpful.