# how to remove reflective shadows

Tags: rendering, node-editor

I have the below scene in Blender Cycles.

[image: rendered scene]

To create volume of the bike's lights I've added two cone meshes.
Here, you can see when I render the scene the cones are creating black shadows on the rays, how can I remove these reflective shadows?

I thought it is happening because the cones are intersected with the rays object, that's why I added boolean modifier to make them intersection free, but that didn't do anything.

Am I missing something in my node setup?
I've attached my blend file as well, please let me know how can I get rid of this?

[image]

Comment: Turn off [ray visibility](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/17910/935) for shadows (you only need camera on) or use a light path node for more control.

Answer (score 2):

### Increase Transparecy bounces

The more objects you add, the more interfaces the light should bounce off to reach a surfaces. This is true also if your objects let the light pass through, like the volumetric and transparent shaded cones are doing.

The black shadow is due to the low number of Transparent bounces allowed in your scene (compared to the scene complexity from this point of view). Light path are being terminated before reaching any light source, so they render blck.

You should increase at least the Max Transparent bounces filed found in Light Path panel by some units.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when I applied a sub surf modifier to one of my models. I was able to correct it by recalculating the normals. You select all with `A` and press `Ctrl+N`

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) but I've just tried out this, it is still the same.