# How do I hide an emitter plane while keeping it's emitted light visible in a cycles render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

This is how you used to be able to do it in blender 2.79
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lsRQQLFVEY

I can't find this option in 2.8

Comment: Does this help: [How to make a cycles light emisson object invisible to the camera?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/17918/31447)

Comment: Hello :). Make sure to use Cycles render engine, Eevee doesn't have this option. Cool username by the way :).

Answer (score 1):

In the object settings, uncheck "Camera" under "Ray Visibility";

This;

[image]

Becomes this;

[image]

This setting removes the emitting object from view (while leaving it's light) regardless of whether you are looking through a camera or the normal viewport.