# Is there a way to keep the shadow but turn off the light in EEVEE render

Tags: light, shadows

I've set up an animation with a object rotating. I've added one point light which is casting a shadow. I like the softness of the shadow, but it's also making my object more brighter. My Scene has environmental HDRI to it, where my object is already getting the reflections when it's rotating. Is there a way to turn off the light from hitting my object?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a cycles light emisson object invisible to the camera?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17910/how-to-make-a-cycles-light-emisson-object-invisible-to-the-camera)

Comment: Is this possible in EEVEE?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do this is using passes, in the passes menu you can enable the shadow pass and some others, then compositing them together. Do an initial render, enter the Compostiting workspace, and you'll see the different inputs for different values.

Comment: I did some goolging and saw this option as well, just turning off the shadow option. So it keeps the light on the object and hides the shadow. https://ibb.co/ZM78dw7