# Lights appearing when rendering Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Is there a way to remove these area lights in Cycles Render? I don't want it to appear.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the representation of the *light object* in the *3D View* and won't appear in the actual render (<kbd>F12</kbd>). You can disable the visibility of non-renderable objects though, by using the [Show Overlays](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/editors/3dview/display/overlays.html?highlight=overlays) toggle in the header of the *3D View*:

[image]

Comment: Might become relevant later: [How to make a cycles light emisson object invisible to the camera?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17910/how-to-make-a-cycles-light-emisson-object-invisible-to-the-camera)